# Teensy + Matlab Serial Communication Problem (12Mbit/S)

Tags: serial, matlab, teensy

Im trying to send some data from my teensy to matlab but matlab didnt even call the callback function:
This is my matlab Funcion:

```
delete(instrfind);
s = serial('COM15','BaudRate',9600,'ReadAsyncMode','continuous');
s.BytesAvailableFcn = {@graf};
fopen(s);
```

This is the callback function I comment it so I can see only the display on console

```
function graf(obj,event)
disp('a');
%{
texto=fscanf(obj);
texto2=strsplit(texto,',');
x=cellfun(@str2num,texto2);
plot(x);
%}
end
```

My teensy baudrate is 9600 and im printing like this

```
Serial.println(se);
```

so it has the terminator all right..
I can see the serial on the arduino serial monitor and in the Realterm

***Edited***

I just find that my teensy work ad 12Mbit/s
[Link](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_serial.html) is there a way to configure matlab serial port at that speed?

Comment: The comment about 12Mbit/s just means the speed effectively gets ignored and it's sent at the USB bus rate, so setting it to 9600 in Matlab should be OK although I've never done serial comms in Matlab.

Comment: I've done serial comms in Matlab, with a teensy, and the baud rate setting is simply ignored. It is only meaningful for external USB<->Serial converters.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note to say I use gnu-octave so I went to [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bytesavailablefcn.html) and the help page said the following:

```
Create the serial port object s for a Tektronix® TDS 210 two-channel oscilloscope connected to the serial port COM1.

s = serial('COM1');

Configure s to execute the callback function instrcallback when 40 bytes are available in the input buffer.

s.BytesAvailableFcnCount = 40;
s.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'byte';
s.BytesAvailableFcn = @instrcallback;
```

Comment: But if I dont know the number of bytes? :/ I need a CR/LF as a Terminate

Comment: In that case you insert a second layer of callbacks. First, receive every single byte (`BytesAvailableFcnCount = 1`). Store all received bytes in a buffer. If the received byte is a line ending, process the buffer as a received line.

Comment: This is in fact very untrue, you can use:
s.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'terminator';
s.Terminator = 13; (LF is 13 in decimal ascii)